# Какие инструменты для генерации кода вы используете в своих .Net проектах?

Tags: c#, .net, кодогенераторы

Не редко, при разработке крупных и сложных приложений приходится заниматься написанием большого количества однотипного простого кода, например при описание DTO и кода, который их сериализует/десериализует. Процесс этот может быть несильно увлекательным и интересным, и может приводить к ошибкам. Для решения этой и не только задачи, весьма успешно можно применять инструменты для автоматической генерации кода.

Хотелось бы узнать какие вообще инструменты для автоматической генерации кода можно использовать в .Net проектах, и для решения каких задач они лучше всего подходят?

Comment: Участник, хочешь нажать `закрыть`? Проходи дальше, не задерживайся.

Comment: Я использую ванильный C#, плюс маленький легко разбираемый DSL. Подходит для всего.

Comment: [t4](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb126445.aspx). @andreycha, а это разве не вопрос на который нельзя дать объективно верный ответ? :-)

Comment: @VladD, DSL написанный на c#? и чем его обрабатывать? сторонней приблудой?

Comment: @Grundy: DSL, написанный вручную, обрабатывается вручную написанным парсером.

Comment: @VladD, хотелось бы глянуть на парсер :-)

Comment: @Grundy: Не могу: NDA :)

Comment: @VladD, какая удобная отмазка ;-)

Comment: @Grundy: А то! Пользуйтесь! :)

Answer (score 2):

Генерацию модели (я предпочитаю бескровную) оставляю за собой (пишу рукми), доступ к БД (опыт пока только с реляционными MS SQL && Postgre SQL) Dapper && EF6+, Dto тоже пилю руками, сериализация/десериализация, там все просто, в зависимости от требования XmlSerializer (забыл уже, когда последний раз использовал)/Json .Net/ BinarySerializer/под кастомные форматы использую рефлексию и MindboxExpressions (см. Nuget), маппинг модели на дто и обратно - AutoMapper (все задается через конфигурацию), валидация = FluentValidation .Net. Ах да, совсем забыл, для логирования/трассировки NLog, IoC = (Ninject|Autofac)